# Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined in this.sidenav.toggle();

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using the mat-sidenav for the navigation drawer

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
   <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="isMobile ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isMobile" class="example-sidenav">
   </mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav-content>
    <falcon-button-toggle *ngIf="isMobile" [field]="htmlButtonToggleConfig"
                    (toggleGroupChange)="toggleChange($event)"></falcon-button-toggle>
   </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

TS file
when the click event appear the slider is undefined.

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('sidenav', { static: true }) public sidenav: MatSidenav;
    toggleChange($event) {
        switch ($event) {
          case ProductDetailsSortFilterEnum.Filter:
            this.sidenav.toggle();
            break;
        }
      }}
```

The this.sidenav is undefined

Comment: Try removing `{static: true}` from `@ViewChild` decorator

Comment: I am using angular 10 it suppose to be that isn't it ??

Comment: It is supposed to be that if you're going to access this element inside ngOnInit and that tag is not inside `*ngIf` or similar